# How to stretch one column of a table by content and decrease widths of others accordingly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a simple HTML table created dynamically according to user uploaded data. It's wrapped into a div with "`col-sm-5`" class (also wrapped into "`row`" div). What I need is for the table to remain of the same size, but for its second column to stretch (change width) according to its content.

As second column stretches, all other columns decrease in width in the same way among each other. Perfectly, there would be a certain limit to maximal width of second column (e.g. 60% of general table width). Here's an example of a table I'm working with:

```
<table class="table table-condensed catalog-table dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>ssssssssssssssss</td><td>3</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>675493859480938590374269824930862436</td><td>67549385</td><td>67549385</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>6.055555555555555555555555555555555555</td><td>56.45</td><td>xyz</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>t</td><td>0</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried applying various combinations of setting "`max-width`", "`width`", "`white-space:nowrap;`" and so on, but nothing seems to work the way I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

You could min-width on the other td's to make the 2nd one responsive:

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed catalog-table dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="min-width:100px">1</th>
                <th >2</th>
                <th style="min-width:100px">3</th>
                <th style="min-width:100px">4</th>
            </tr>       
        </thead>    
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>ssssssssssssssss</td>
            <td >3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>675493859480938590374269824930862436</td>
            <td>67549385</td>
            <td>67549385</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
               <td>6.055555555555555555555555555555555555</td>
            <td>56.45</td>
            <td>xyz</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>t</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63sg85Lr/

Answer (score 0):

A fix to avoid overlap in general would be to add class `.table-responsive` to the table.

But if you don't like the overflow solution at all, I would suggest to mimic your table using divs or set a class in your table and give table and table elemets (tr,td etc) `display: block` or `display: inline-block` .
Then you will be able to use the `max-width` rules you like to apply.

Your table will be a little mess in first until you find the right formula for your needs.

I hope that helps a bit.